# CSV to date and float

Tags: performance, go

I'm currently writing a small program which converts CSV-files into structs to be used for further prosessing. The csv lines look like this

```
20140102,09:30,38.88,38.88,38.82,38.85,67004
```

I have 500 files, each about 20-30 MB.
My code works just fine, but I can't help wondering if there isn't a better way to convert these files than what I'm doing now. 
First reading the file and converting to csv records (pseudo code)

```
    data, err := ioutil.ReadFile(path)
    if err != nil {
        ... 
    }
    r := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
    records, err := r.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        ... 
    }
```

Then looping over all the records and doing

```
    parsedTime, err := time.Parse("2006010215:04", record[0]+record[1])
    if err != nil {
        return model.ZorroT6{}, time.Time{}, err
    }

    t6.Date = ConvertToOle(parsedTime)
    if open, err := strconv.ParseFloat(record[2], 32); err == nil {
        t6.Open = float32(open)
    }
    if high, err := strconv.ParseFloat(record[3], 32); err == nil {
        t6.High = float32(high)
    }
    if low, err := strconv.ParseFloat(record[4], 32); err == nil {
        t6.Low = float32(low)
    }
    if close, err := strconv.ParseFloat(record[5], 32); err == nil {
        t6.Close = float32(close)
    }
    if vol, err := strconv.ParseInt(record[6], 10,32); err == nil {
        t6.Vol = int32(vol)
    }
```

For example I have to go through []byte -> string -> float64 -> float32 to get my float values. What could I do to improve this code?

EDIT: Just to be clear I don't really *need* to improve the performance, I'm just better trying to understand Go and what performance optimization that could be applied to a problem like this. For example it seems like a lot of overhead to create loads of strings and float64 when I have a byte slice and want a float32.

Comment: I don't think the code needs improvement. How long does it take now and how long do you wish it to take? Have you profiled your program and are you sure this is where bottle-neck is?

Comment: I don't really need to improve the speed, but in the interest of better understanding go, I wanted to give this a try. I've profiled the application and currently most time is spent in readRecord (called by readAll), time.Parse and parseFloat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one problem I see that needs fix:

Do not use `ioutil.ReadFile` together with `bytes.NewReader`. It reads all the contents into the memory, which is inefficient when the file is large.

Instead, use `os.Open(file)`, it perfectly provides a `io.Reader` that `csv.NewReader` can utilize. Do not forget to close the file and handle errors.

If you still want to improve performance:

1. Since your csv file is of fixed format, it is possible to using raw bytes instead provided by `bufio` instead of `csv`.
2. You can copy and paste the underlying code in `strconv` and `time` to avoid general code that is not of your need.

But I think they are not worth the trouble.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at using os.Open() instead. I actually looked at bufio quickly, but since I still couldn't find a way to convert the []byte from bufio to float32 or time without going through string, I never went further. But I guess I could combine 1) and 2), and the functions to take a []byte rather than string. Might be a good project for a rainy day ;-) Thanks again, really appreciate your response.

Comment: @Daniel please note that it may harm your future maintenance.

Comment: Absolutely, this is nothing I would do for a production system. More as a learning experience and to understand what kind of performance gains you could gain from more extreme measures like extracting and modifying internal APIs. The code currently parses ~10GB of data in about 100 seconds, which is more than fast enough.

Comment: I tried doing this, just for fun. Making parseFloat return a float32 directly did absolutely *nothing* for the performance. Changing it to accept a []byte instead of string cut the allocations in half, so I guess that might be worth exploring further if you had issues with that. But like you already said; probably not worth the trouble.